# How to type in notepad using python

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to open a new notepad but I don't know how to type in the notepad using python.

Please help me, thanks!

```
import subprocess as sp
programName = "notepad.exe"
fileName = "file.txt"
sp.Popen([programName, fileName])
```

Comment: Are you asking for writing in a text file with Python?

Comment: Take a look at the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package on PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
t=open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\File.txt", "w")
t.write("Whatever your message is")
t.close()
```

This would open (or create if non-existent) and write to a text file with: "Whatever your message is" inside.

You may also find section 7.2 in here helpful:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html